Guess number recursion Python
I'm very new to Python. I want to write a code for the "Bulls and Cows" game, using recursion."Bulls and Cows" is a logic game where the goal is to guess the program's secret number. All the digits of this number must be different.
The number of "bulls" is digits in the guess that are in the correct position.
The number of "cows" are digits in the guess that are in the program's number but are located in the wrong position. Specifically, the non-bull digits in the guess that could be rearranged such that they become bulls.
I have some code, but it doesn't work. Would be grateful for any hint!
import random
    
progNum=str(random.randint(1000,9999))
print("Guess the number. It contains 4 digits.")

userNum=list(input("Enter your number: "))

l1=progNum
l2=userNum


def check(bulls,cows):  
    
    if cows==4 and bulls==4:
        return ('right number')
    
    else:
        bulls=0
        cows=0
        if l1[0]==l2[0]:            
            cows=cows+1
            print('Cows{}'.format(cows))        
        if l2[0] in l1:
            bulls=bulls+1
            print('Bulls{}'.format(bulls))
        if l1[1]==l2[1]:
            cows=cows+1
            print('Cows{}'.format(cows))
        if l2[1] in l1:
            bulls=bulls+1
            print('Bulls{}'.format(bulls))
        if l1[2]==l2[2]:
            cows=cows+1
            print('Cows{}'.format(cows))
        if l2[2] in l1:
            bulls=bulls+1
            print('Bulls{}'.format(bulls))
        if l1[3]==l2[3]:
            cows=cows+1
            print('Cows{}'.format(cows))
        if l2[3] in l1:
            bulls=bulls+1
            print('Bulls{}'.format(bulls))
    check(bulls,cows)

     

I made a base condition for the game termination as
if cows==4 and bulls==4:return ('right number'), but it seems that without without specifying the number of attempts, it continues until a number is guessed. I think if the base condition could be the number of attempts, like cows=cows+(x), where x the number of attempts.

Don't use recursion here. Recursion is limited by the stack size (or more specifically, a hard-coded limit on how much stack space is allowed to be used). Use an ordinary loop instead, which is not similarly constrained.

The duplicate solves just one problem. You also never call check, nor do you ever let the the user enter a second number if the first guess is incorrect.

(Part of my confusion is unfamiliarity with what the "Bulls and Cows" game is; that should be explained in the question, instead of assuming we are all familiar with the rules.)

Thank you. "Bulls and Cows" is a logic game where the goal is to guess the program's secret number. All the digits of this number must be different. The number of "bulls" are digits in the guess that are in the correct position. The number of "cows" are digits in the guess that are in the program's number but are located in the wrong position. Specifically, the non-bull digits in the guess that could be rearranged such that they become bulls.

@chepner Bulls and Cows is a pretty old, well-known game. It's like Wordle, except with digits instead of letters.

I want to understand if i can return the number of bulls if i don't have the number of attempts.

If you switch this to use a loop as @chepner suggests, then counting attempts is as trivial as incrementing a variable by 1.  Then if you wished to end the game after n attempts, you could just have that as a condition check inside the loop and break.
